# SSIS Filtered SQL Server OLE DB Datasource

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm writing a data transfer application that syncs two databases of similar, but differing schemas. I'm partway through, but I was wondering if SSIS might make things easier. I'm trying to figure out if it's the right solution for me, but I can't do something very simple.

The sync application is only moving subsets of data, so I need to grab rows that match a parameter. I don't see any filtering options on OLE DB datasources, though. How do I accomplish a simple where clause in SSIS? Do I have to write it myself, or is SSIS smart enough to handle it?

Comment: you can include the where in your ole db data source to filter the rows or you can add a Conditional Split after the data source.

Comment: @Jayvee Please elaborate on adding a where clause in the ole db datasource. I didn't see the option in the SSIS-DT (2012) gui... Make your reply an answer so, if it works, I can upvote and accept for your rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you double click on the OLE DB souce, in 'Data access method' by default you'll see 'Table or View' but you can select SQL Command to enter your sql, and this will be used by the ole data source to extract the data.

Comment: Great! Thanks. To make it work, I had to select the SQL command option, like Jayvee said. Then I chose build query, right clicked, added the table. Then I selected all columns. But to specify a parameter, you have to close and re-open the window. Then I could type "=?" in the Filter column. Then, I clicked the Parameters button, and I could assign a parameter.